# Dojo getting element attribute ID from node

Tags: dojo

Hey all the following code searches for a span that has an inner text of "Ex: Bob" and goes back one element (which would be the **input** element).

```
<input 
  dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode,_aroundNode" 
  dojoattachevent="onblur:onBlur,onfocus:onFocus,onkeyup:onKeyUp" 
  id="2c6af1dc-80cb-44f2-864d-1fb00216895dF_SingleLine-widget" 
  name="" 
  class="dijitReset dijitTextBox notDojoDndHandle" 
  type="text" 
  tabindex="0" 
  aria-label="text" 
  width="auto" 
  value="" 
  aria-describedby="2c6af1dc-80cb-44f2-864d-1fb00216895dF_SingleLine-widget-placeholder"
  style="max-width: 2.5em; width: 90%;">

<span 
  class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField" 
  id="2c6af1dc-80cb-44f2-864d-1fb00216895dF_SingleLine-widget-placeholder" 
  style="max-width: 2.5em; width: 90%;">
  Ex: Bob
</span>
```

and the JS:

```
dojo.query("span.dijitPlaceHolder.dijitInputField").forEach(function(node, index, arr){
      if (node.innerHTML === 'Ex: Bob') {
          var foundIt = dojo.query(node).prev();

          dojo.addClass(foundIt, "testClass");
      }
});
```

Instead of what I need it to do:

class="dijitReset dijitTextBox notDojoDndHandle testClass" 
It still has this:

class="dijitReset dijitTextBox notDojoDndHandle"

Questions is: How can I get that input's *ID* from the node? (foundIt) since I need a ID in order for the **.addClass** to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things to notice here:

#### Be sure that the DOM is loaded

To do that, wrap your code inside a `dojo.addOnLoad()` function, for example:

```js
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    // Your code
});
```

#### Trim your text

You're verifying if the inner HTML is `"Ex: Bob"`, however, currently your inner HTML also contains some newline characters and probably some tabs as well (because you put it on a new line). To fix that, you should trim your content before comparing, for example:

```js
if (node.innerHTML.trim() === 'Ex: Bob') {
    // Your code
}
```

#### `dojo.query` returns a `dojo.NodeList`

The `dojo.query` module returns a `dojo.NodeList`, which is not compatible with the `dojo.addClass()` function which requires either an ID or a DOM node.

A `dojo.NodeList` actually is an array of DOM nodes, so you could write something as:

```js
var foundIt = dojo.query(node).prev();
dojo.addClass(foundIt[0], "testClass"); // Retrieve the element at index 0
```

Or even better, the `dojo.NodeList` also has a function called `addClass()` which applies to  these lists, for example:

```js
dojo.query(node).prev().addClass("testClass"); // Short and easy
```

#### Be sure to include the proper modules

The `dojo.NodeList::prev()` functionality requires `dojo.NodeList-traverse` to be loaded, while the `dojo.NodeList::addClass()` functionality requires `dojo.NodeList-dom` to be loaded. I don't know which modules you actually have to list, but I started with Dojo myself since 1.7 and I have the habit to list all modules, for example:

```js
dojo.require("dojo.query");
dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-traverse");
dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-dom");
```

If you did all that, your code should work, as you can see in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69TDn/

Answer (score 0):

What you have done must already be working w.r.t. addClass method. Because dojo.addClass takes **A DOM node or its node id (as a string)** as its first parameter. Refer [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/query.html). Dojo.query returns the dom node and this is the second parameter. If it is not working for you I would suggest, you check the dojo.query method with console.log to check if you are infact getting the right node you intended to modify. May be that is not right.